# Split data frame by date

Tags: python

The data I ingest provides details for two dates (min and max dates) and I need to split them into two sheets. What is the code that I need to use to do this please? I’m fairly new to python and just learning.

Not sure where to start

Comment: provide more details about your problem. this is easy to get the result

Comment: In the date column there are rows dated 4th May and other dated 5th May. I need to extract the rows for the 5th of MAy into a new excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split off a sub_DF using the date value. As a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['May','June', 'May', 'June'],
                   'val' : [1, 2, 3, 4]
                   })

df_may = df[df['month'].eq('May')]
```

this DF can then be saved to excel

Alternatively you could use groupby to split off all the sub_DFs by month name and save these in a List:

```
df_g = df.groupby('month')

df_month_list = [df_g.get_group(g) for g in df_g.groups]
```

the new dataframes split from the original are `df_month_list[0]` and `df_month_list[1]`; these can then be saved as required in Excel